# Не работает .html.render() в Requests-HTML

Tags: python, requests-html

Решил попробовать Requests-HTML. Простой запрос отрабатывает, а с JavaScrip выдаёт ошибку. Попробовал разные сайты, устанавливал стандартно, может ли влиять ранее установленный requests? Windows 10, Python 3.9.

```
<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\К\serg\python\stackoverflow\dict1.py", line 9, in <module>
    r.html.render()
  File "C:\Users\К\serg\python\stackoverflow\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "C:\Users\К\serg\python\stackoverflow\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 730, in browser
    self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)
  File "C:\Users\К\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\К\serg\python\stackoverflow\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 714, in browser
    self._browser = await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=not(self.verify), headless=True, args=self.__browser_args)
  File "C:\Users\К\serg\python\stackoverflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 307, in launch
    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
  File "C:\Users\К\serg\python\stackoverflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 168, in launch
    self.browserWSEndpoint = get_ws_endpoint(self.url)
  File "C:\Users\К\serg\python\stackoverflow\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 227, in get_ws_endpoint
    raise BrowserError('Browser closed unexpectedly:\n')
pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:
```

pyppeteer и Chromium загружены. Что не так? После запуска и распечатывания первого принта, секунд 20 тишины и затем вылетает с ошибкой.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession


session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('https://reddit.com')
print(r)

r.html.render()
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверил на python 3.7.9, все работает.

[image: xd]

Попробуйте удалить pyppeteer и requests_html, а потом заново установить.
Возможно разные версии модулей конфликтуют. Выполните по порядку:

- pip uninstall requests_html
- pip uninstall pyppeteer
- pip install requests_html